# PDF Rendering in Recyclerview causes UI block

Tags: android, performance, pdf, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load pdf pages in the recyclerview android. Currently, I am using `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0` library to render my PDFs. Here is my recyclerview adapter,

```java
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mPdfPathsList;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mDimensionsList;
    private Activity mActivity;


    public class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        PDFView pdfView;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pdfView = (PDFView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        }
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> pdfPathList, Activity activity, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dimensionList) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mPdfPathsList = pdfPathList;
        mDimensionsList = dimensionList;

    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        return new DataObjectHolder(view);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mDimensionsList.get(position).get(0), mDimensionsList.get(position).get(1));
        holder.pdfView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPdfPathsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(DataObjectHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

        holder.pdfView.useBestQuality(false);
        holder.pdfView.fromAsset(mPdfPathsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()))
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .pages(0)
                .load();
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is when I use PDF of large size the scroll for recyclerview becomes very sticky and sometimes it gets stuck.
I think its because when I load the pdf using the pdfView then its taking too much time to Draw it. Can anyone suggest me how I can overcome the scroll sticky problem?

Also I am loading pdf inside `onViewAttachedToWindow()` method because if I load the pdf inside `onBindViewHolder()` then I get blank item for recyclerview when it is recycled.

Comment: Showing a PDF in recycler view is obviously memory consuming task. Try to look for generating a preview. Cache it in form of bitmap and do lazy loading.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi I have done this by getting bitmaps of pages and show in ImageView. It works perfect. But what I am looking at is the functionality of zooming of the pdf and without losing quality. Can u suggest any other means by which I can achieve this?

Comment: Which PDF render lib you are using ? Showing full pdf in recyclerview is not good. And if you are allowing to zoom in zoom out in list section where multiple items with their respective pdfs are listed is bad design. All libs takes care of zoom in zoom out functionality by default. I am not sure where exactly you are using recyclerview.

Comment: I am using "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0" library for rendering pdf. My pdf files consist of only one page. So its like showing one page in item of recyclerview.

Comment: so is PDFView alone is not capable to handle multiple ages and scroll ?